# Exporting data from excel to html based on column

Tags: excel

Exporting data from excel to html based on column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not wanting to overwrite existing files, you'll have to remember the old filename, check if a new one occurs and reorganize opening and closing as follows. Take care to use fully qualified range references.

```
Sub Html()
    'fully qualify your sheet range references!
    With Sheet1                             ' << using project's worksheet Code(Name)
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    
        Dim r As Long                       ' don't mix variable names with existing properties like row
        Dim oldFn As String                 ' remember prior filename
        Dim currFn As String                ' define current filename
        For r = 1 To lastRow
            currFn = .Cells(r, "A").Value   ' define current filename
            If currFn <> oldFn Then         ' check if a new filename occurs in loop
                oldFn = currFn              ' remember the old filename
                If r > 1 Then Close #1
                Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\txt\" & currFn & ".txt" For Output As #1
            End If
            Print #1, .Cells(r, "B").Value  ' write text line
        Next
        Close #1
    End With
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Of course, just insert ` Print #1, "</html>"` before the close statement. Suppose you want a comparable insertion after each Open file statement starting with  a `<html>` tag opening. @Eben

Comment: That's right, you have to change to this as well: `If r > 1 Then Print #1, "</html>": Close #1` @Eben

Comment: You slightly misunderstood my comment; therefore I edited your code below to meet your additional requirements. @Eben